# Make https the Default when Page Loading

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I am running a web site, from an Ubuntu 16 (LTS) server running on AWS EC2.  I have set the following input rules for my security group on AWS

```
Type    Protocol    Port Range    Source
HTTP    TCP            80        0.0.0.0/0
SSH     TCP            22        72.81.131.89/32
HTTPS   TCP            443       0.0.0.0/0
```

On My Ubuntu server, I have set up SSL as described [here](https://www.rapidsslonline.com/blog/install-ssl-certificate-on-apache2-ubuntu-server/).  I have also edited /etc/apache2/ports.conf to be the following.

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 8080

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I do not have a file, /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.

I have created a file, /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, with the following content

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName example.com:443
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.cert
ServerAdmin MYWEBGUY@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errorSSL.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/accessSSL.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have gone to /etc/apache2/ssl and entered

```
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out example.com.crt -keyout example.com.key
```

That procedure worked without errors.

When I enter

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

I get

```
Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:
Module setenvif already enabled
Considering dependency mime for ssl:
Module mime already enabled
Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:
Module socache_shmcb already enabled
Module ssl already enabled
```

When I open my browser and enter

```
https://example.com
```

my web page opens with the green lock saying the site is secure.  However, when I just enter

```
example.com
```

I get a regular http connection and a message saying the connection to the site is not secure.

How can I make https the default when the user just enters

```
example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force a redirect to the SSL site when a user hits the not-SSL site.
I will add a section like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

or better use a Rewrite rule to redirect all the requests to the SSL site:

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

look at the [apache wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) for further info